# How to determine the screen width/height using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, screen, css

I want to set the width & height of a `Window` dynamically based on the user screens maximum width/height. How can I determine this programmatically?

Comment: Is maximising your window not acceptable?

Comment: @Lazarus: No, not for the case I want to handle.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For the primary screen:

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight
```

(*Note that there are also some other primary screen related properties which depend on various factors, `Full*` & `Maximised*`*)

Virtual screen:

```
SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth
SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight
```

Comment: What about based on current resolution? How to get that?

Comment: I would think this does use the current resolution, have you tried it?

Comment: Finally an answer to this question! Does VirtualScreenWidth[Height] not get updated when the user changes scaling while the application open? On Win10 it looks like you have to restart the application for these values to get repopulated.

Comment: @Hashman: Cannot tell you anything about that, don't even have a win 10 setup.

Answer (score 14):

If you want the specific dimensions of the monitor your program is running on (if someone is running more than one monitor) you could also use:

```
var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this); //this being the wpf form 
var currentScreen = Screen.FromHandle(helper.Handle);
```

This will return a screen object referencing the monitor the program is running on. From there you can use the `currentScreen.Bounds.Width` / `Height` property (for the full size) or the `currentScreen.WorkingArea.Width` / `Height` (minus task bar, etc.) depending on what you want.

Answer (score 9):

use    Screen Object

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SizeChanged` event

```
SizeChanged="MyWindow_SizeChanged"
```

Then in your event handler,

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.MinWidth > 0 && this.MinHeight > 0)
    {
        double heightScaleFactor = e.NewSize.Height / this.MinHeight;
        double widthScaleFactor = e.NewSize.Width / this.MinWidth;            
        mainGrid.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(heightScaleFactor, widthScaleFactor);
    }
}
```

where `MainGrid` is a container for all the contents in `MyWindow`.

Comment: Not sure how this addresses the question.

Comment: It is a valid post, but as Lazarus mentioned.. "it doesn't address the question" :)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't use any of the solutions above under .NET 4.0.30319.42000 with Windows 10 Enterprise when calling it from the Ranorex Studio 8.0.1+git.8a3e1a6f, so I used the line

```
using WinForms = System.Windows.Forms;
[…]
                SetWindowPos(processes[0].MainWindowHandle,
                    0,
                    y,
                    x,
                    WinForms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width,
                    WinForms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height,
                    SWP.SHOWWINDOW);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I'm using Ranorex too and was trying to adapt the other answers but you've hit the nail on the head...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen height and width:

```
int height = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height;
int width = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;
```

Then set the Window's `Height` and `Width` properties to those in the Initialization.

```
this.Height = height;
this.Width = width;
```

Works to get the screen's height and width in WinForms or in ASP .NET.  No muss, no fuss, except you'll need to reference the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly in your project if it's not a WinForm project.