# WPF Screen Resolution

Tags: wpf

I have been working on WPF desktop application and have graphics according to a particular screen resolution. I need to scale the all the margins based on screen resolution. How can I achieve this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927540/how-to-get-the-size-of-the-current-screen-in-wpf 
or this

Comment: The link answers for multi-screen problem and I dont care abut multi screen as of now and what does "this" refers to in your comment, its not a link

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
```

make a little search :)

Comment: Yeah I did that, but how would I adjust the margins.For eg:<TextBlock Width="Auto" Margin="15,0,0,0"/> is designed for 1366x768. But this margin would be set for all screens independent of the resolution. I ned answer for this, if its a valid question and it makes sense

Comment: @yshooooo in this case you better look for Grid.RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions

Comment: So you mean to say, if the textblock is of width 30, then i should create a grid and have its ColumnDefinitions defined as 1* and 2*. That would be a lot of work I guess, and also I cant achieve accuracy for the all the definitions. Isn't there some other way?

Comment: @yshooooo you want to adjust margin between textbox or change the with when resolution changed ?

Comment: want to adjust the margins.But it would be a plus point if you could  give answer for both of them

Answer (score 0):

To get the `Screen Resolutions` we have to use the dpi factor value of system, use the below code as per [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/JeffFerguson/archive/2010/06/14/calculating-screen-resolutions-using-wpf.aspx) (please read it in full to understand):

```
using System.Windows.Media;


Window mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
PresentationSource mainWindowPresentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(mainWindow);
Matrix m = mainWindowPresentationSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
double dpiWidthFactor = m.M11;
double dpiHeightFactor = m.M22;
double ScreenHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * dpiHeightFactor; //calculated correct value
double ScreenWidth = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * dpiWidthFactor; //calculated correct value
```

Comment: mainWindowPresentationSource is always null for me - why?

Comment: @MarkRichman Your MainWindow object should be loaded before calling this code, I think that is the reason you are getting null. Try putting your code in Window.Loded event or some other event when Load is completed..

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to :-  System.Windows.Forms

```
var width = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
```