# How to set the size of a WinForms Window to Auto?

Tags: wpf, windows, winforms, resize, dpi

How can I set the size of a WinForms Window to Auto! I do not want to give it a specific size, want it to adjust to its content!

For example in WPF we have something like this:

```
Height="Auto" Width="420" SizeToContent="Height"
```

The reason I want to set it this way is that the window  shrinks in Windows 10 on 4k resolution!

Comment: There is no similar behavior for WinForms (AFAIK). What you can do is to read the Screen size and apply some kind of calc to set your Height and Width

Comment: @Steve That is what I feared!

Comment: Well, that's just the tip of the iceberg. Other problems are waiting here. For example font-size

Comment: @Steve I know! I'm working a legacy code which was written before WPF!

Comment: Sorry for that first post ... try this link [it is from code behind but it can help u](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426930/how-can-i-set-wpf-window-size-is-25-percent-of-relative-monitor-screen)

Comment: Use the form's AutoSize and AutoSizeMode properties.  But surely you are [ignoring the real reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e/13228495#13228495).