# wpf multi monitor screen height

Tags: c#, wpf

some of my controls have to be the same height of the screen so on the height property I do this binding

```
Height="x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight"
```

however, I am going to have multiple monitors in this app.  so when I move the window with the controls to the "other" monitors is that now considered the primary screen? if not then how do I get the ScreenHeight of the current screen that the window/controls are on?

Comment: Wouldn't maximizing the window be a better option?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight` the property you are looking for?

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.virtualscreenheight(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Have re-read you question. No, it is not. You can PInvoke WinAPI as discriped [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927540/how-to-get-the-size-of-the-current-screen-in-wpf):