# WPF Window Full screen vs Window Maximized

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7

In WPF, whenever I set WindowState to Maximized, I get a full screen without border. 
How to get a full screen with border, like the one shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhCVz.png).

This image is of Windows File Explorer(with border) and is only shared to show the borders. It has nothing to do with my application.

I want my WPF window to have similar borders when maximized.

Comment: My file explorer expands the same as my WPF..

Comment: I shared the File Explorer window just to show windows7 supports 2 types of full screen. One with border and other without Border.
Kindly, unplug your monitor adapter and replug to see the difference.

Comment: To me this seems not to be an issue with WPF but seems to be an indication of an issue with your Windows 7 installation. (Suggestion: Install a vanilla Windows 7 in a VM, and try your program there and compare the behavior of the vanilla Win7 installation with your current Win7 installation).

Comment: Set the window height and width to screensize... see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2118993/2289942

Comment: @MuralikrishnanRamanathan Im sorry but Im not going to unplug a monitor just because you think your bug will show.

Comment: Hi BugFinder, Please check the 2 screens. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsdesktop/en-US/078c613a-a11c-4ddc-a792-84315ce875f4/in-windows7-when-window-is-maximized-it-does-not-show-border?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Comment: How does that link help the question - you have already shown the picture with border in your question, we know what it looks like without the border?

Comment: Hi Paul, I thought I didnt convey the question clearly, since the image without border was not shared.

Comment: @BugFinder All I need is the method call to do both. I did not say the one with the border is a bug. Did I? WindowState.Maximized will maximize it to a borderless window. If you assign height and width of the work area/ monitor area of the screen, it will still show a borderless window.

Answer (score 0):

because WindowState does not control the border at all.
use WindowStyle for that.
full screen without border would be WindowStyle.None
sounds like you want WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow