# WPF Current Screen Dimensions

Tags: c#, wpf

Throughout all my applications, if I wish to size a window according to the current monitor resolution I use the following:

```
     System.Drawing.Rectangle workingArea = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromHandle(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(App.Current.MainWindow).Handle).WorkingArea;
```

However, I have one client, who uses multiple monitors, where this is just not working. The resized window is spanning across to a second monitor. Only this one client. I've tested this using multiple monitors and it works fine.

Can anyone please suggest a better/alternative method?

Comment: Can't you simply maximize the window?

Comment: It's a dialog, using MUI. Dialogs cannot be "maximised". I set the form dimensions at runtime , as shown.
Why on all the dozens of PC's which have multiple monitors attached, does it mess up on this one? I've seen a screenshot, and the window is spanning across to the second monitor

Comment: duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927540/how-to-get-the-size-of-the-current-screen-in-wpf)?

Answer (score 0):

For any `FrameworkElement` you can get it's rendered size (`Height` and `Width`) by using this.

```
FrameworkElement.ActualWidth;
FrameworkElement.ActualHeight;
```

so in this case you can use it for your window.

Comment: Why on all the dozens of PC's which have multiple monitors attached, does it mess up on this one? I've seen a screenshot, and the window is spanning across to the second monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Windows Forms' class `System.Windows.Forms.Screen`. It allows for screen enumeration, and to get your WPF window's screen, use this `Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle)` snippet. There is, however, an issue with hi-res screens - you need to convert WPF's 96 dpi to whatever pixel density your monitor has.