# How to position a dialog window on top left corner of current screen?

Tags: wpf, dialog, window, screen

I'm trying to position a WPF dialog window on the top left corner of the **current** screen. However, I do not know how to get those coordinates for any other screen than the primary one.
For the primary screen Top and Left would be 0. However, for any other screen I would need to know the offset.
I could have a second or even third screen. To make things more complicated: **Those other screens could (in theory) be positioned to the left, top or below the primary screen.**

I did some research but was not able to find a solution. Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2118993/7252182)?

Comment: mm8's suggestion pointed me to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I just did not see the neccessary properties: Each Screen object has its own Top and Left property within its WorkingArea.

This works for me:

```
var topLeftCornerOfMainWindow = new System.Drawing.Point((int)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Left, (int)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Top);
var currentScreen = Screen.FromPoint(topLeftCornerOfMainWindow);

this.Top = currentScreen.WorkingArea.Top;
this.Left = currentScreen.WorkingArea.Left;
this.Width = currentScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
this.Height = currentScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting values to Window.Left and Window.Top:

```
window.Left = 0;
window.Top = 0-window.Height;

window.ShowDialog();
```