# Set window size to fit content, but stop the window width from going beyond screen width

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a sort of a popup window like the [Overloads window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/media/vs2015_param_info.png?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio. And just like the Overloads window, it can pop up pretty much anywhere on the screen.

I have a `Window` that has a child `TextBlock` control.
The `Window` changes its size according to the `TextBlock` size by setting its `SizeToContent` property to `WidthAndHeight`. If the `TextBlock` `Text` is too long, the `Window` resizes its width beyond the screen's width resulting in a partially visible `Window`. I would like the `Text` to wrap when it reaches the end of the screen, so to say.

I tried setting the `TextBlock` `TextWrapping` property to `Wrap` to hopefully stop this behavior, but it doesn't help because of the `SizeToContent` property being set. Any suggestions/workarounds?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the `MaxWidth` property of the window to the width of the screen, e.g.:

```
TextBlock text = new TextBlock()
{
    Text = "some very long string...",
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
};
Window window = new Window()
{
    SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
    Content = text,
    MaxWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
};
window.Show();
```

[How to get the size of the current screen in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927540/how-to-get-the-size-of-the-current-screen-in-wpf)

Comment: That would be the solution if the position of the `Window` were fixed, but the `Window` can appear pretty much anywhere on the screen (if the `Window` appears on the right side of the screen, setting the `MaxWidth` prop to `PrimaryScreenWidth` doesn't restrict it from overflowing). I'll add this explanation to the question to avoid further misconceptions.

Comment: The solution is still to set the `MaxWidth`. You just need to calculate what to set it to. A hint: Look at the `Left` property of the window.

Comment: I just would use mm8's answer, (MaxWidth=PrimaryScreenWidth-MyWindow.Left), Then I would just add the calculous to `LocationChanged` event.