# Swap vertical ScrollBar side based on window position on screen

Tags: wpf, window, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I have a window that contains a `ScrollViewer`, What i want is to swap the vertical `ScrollBar` side to the left if the window is on the right side of the screen and vice-versa.

Here is my current `ScrollViewer` template in a `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Style x:Key="ScrollViewerWithoutCollapsedVerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0">
                        <ScrollContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility, Converter={StaticResource ComputedScrollBarVisibilityWithoutCollapse}}" />
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What would be the way to go on from there?

Comment: By `if the window is on the right side of the screen and vice-versa` you mean when a window is *docked* to the left or right side of the screen?

Comment: I was more thinking about when the window crosses the middle of the screen, i am not sure yet about docking though, those windows are frameless overlays that the user can move around on top of another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positioning the `ScrollBar` inside of your `ScrollViewer` depending on the window position requires you to know:

- The Size of the containing window to know where the center is
- The window location to determine whether it crossed the center of the screen or not
- The screen size to know where the center of the screen even is

What makes it addionally difficult are the following factors

- You need to get the information from your `ScrollViewer` that is a child of the window that could change
- Size changes and location changes can also change the side of the screen
- Screen sizes are [difficult to get in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927540/how-to-get-the-size-of-the-current-screen-in-wpf), especially in multi-monitor setups

I will show you a working example to achieve what you want for the primary screen. Since this is another block for a another question, you can start from there and adapt it to your requirements.

In order to tackle the issues above, we will use the `SizeChanged` and `LocationChanged` events to detect changes of a window in size and location. We will use the `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth` to get the screen width, which *can*, but may not work in multi-monitor setups with different resolutions.

Your control will alter the default `ScrollViewer` behavior and appearance. I think it is best to create a custom control to make it reusable, because dealing with this in XAML with other techniques might become messy.

### Create the custom scroll viewer

Create a new type `AdaptingScrollViewer` that inherits from `ScrollViewer` like below. I have commented the code for you to explain how it works.

```
public class AdaptingScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
{
   // We need this dependency property internally, so that we can bind the parent window
   // and get notified when it changes 
   private static readonly DependencyProperty ContainingWindowProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ContainingWindow), typeof(Window),
         typeof(AdaptingScrollViewer), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnContainingWindowChanged));

   // Getter and setter for the dependency property value for convenient access
   public Window ContainingWindow
   {
      get => (Window)GetValue(ContainingWindowProperty);
      set => SetValue(ContainingWindowProperty, value);
   }

   static AdaptingScrollViewer()
   {
      // We have to override the default style key, so that we can apply our new style
      // and control template to it
      DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(AdaptingScrollViewer),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(AdaptingScrollViewer)));
   }

   public AdaptingScrollViewer()
   {
      // Relative source binding to the parent window
      BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ContainingWindowProperty,
         new Binding { RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(Window), 1) });

      // When the control is removed, we want to clean up and remove the event handlers
      Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
   }

   private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      RemoveEventHandlers(ContainingWindow);
   }

   // This method is called when the window in the relative source binding changes
   private static void OnContainingWindowChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      var scrollViewer = (AdaptingScrollViewer)d;
      var oldContainingWindow = (Window)e.OldValue;
      var newContainingWindow = (Window)e.NewValue;

      // If the scroll viewer got detached from the current window and attached to a new
      // window, remove the previous event handlers and add them to the new window
      scrollViewer.RemoveEventHandlers(oldContainingWindow);
      scrollViewer.AddEventHandlers(newContainingWindow);
   }

   private void AddEventHandlers(Window window)
   {
      if (window == null)
         return;

      // Add events to react to changes of the window size and location
      window.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
      window.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;

      // When we add new event handlers, then adapt the scrollbar position immediately
      SetScrollBarColumn();
   }

   private void RemoveEventHandlers(Window window)
   {
      if (window == null)
         return;

      // Remove the event handlers to prevent memory leaks
      window.SizeChanged -= OnSizeChanged;
      window.LocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;
   }

   private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      SetScrollBarColumn();
   }

   private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      SetScrollBarColumn();
   }

   private void SetScrollBarColumn()
   {
      if (ContainingWindow == null)
         return;


      // Get the column in the control template grid depending on the center of the screen
      var column = ContainingWindow.Left <= GetHorizontalCenterOfScreen(ContainingWindow) ? 0 : 2;

      // The scrollbar is part of our control template, so we can get it like this
      var scrollBar = GetTemplateChild("PART_VerticalScrollBar");

      // If someone overwrote our control template and did not add a scrollbar, ignore
      // it instead of crashing the application, because everybody makes mistakes sometimes
      scrollBar?.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, column);
   }

   private static double GetHorizontalCenterOfScreen(Window window)
   {
      return SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth / 2 - window.Width / 2;
   }
}
```

### Creating a control template

Now our new `AdaptingScrollViewer` nees a control template. I took your example and adapted the style and control template and commented the changes, too.

```
<!-- Target the style to our new type and base it on scroll viewer to get default properties -->
<Style x:Key="AdaptingScrollViewerStyle"
                TargetType="{x:Type local:AdaptingScrollViewer}"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ScrollViewer}}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <!-- The control template must also target the new type -->
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AdaptingScrollViewer}">
            <Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <!-- Added a new column for the left position of the scrollbar -->
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0">
                  <ScrollContentPresenter/>
               </Border>
               <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.Column="2"
                                   Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
               <!-- Added a column span to correct the horizontal scroll bar -->
               <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                   Orientation="Horizontal"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                   Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
            </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

You need to add the following style after the style above in your resource dictionary, too, so that the `AdaptingScrollViewer` get styled automatically.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:AdaptingScrollViewer}" BasedOn="{StaticResource AdaptingScrollViewerStyle}"/>
```

### Showing the result

In in your main XAML create the control like this to enable both scrollbars and see the result.

```
<local:AdaptingScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do in order to put a scrollbar on the left of a scrollviewer rather than right is to set the flowdirection to RightToLeft.

You will then need to explicitly set the flowdirection to lefttoright on a container within that to stop it affecting contents.

Here's some experimental markup to consider:

```
        <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer  FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                       Name="sv"
                       >
            <StackPanel  FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                <TextBlock Text="Banana"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Banana"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Banana"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Click="ToggleButton_Click"
                      Content="Flow"
                          />
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```