# Select view depending on screen resolution

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have a WPF application made for an LCD display with a specific resolution. The WPF application is fixed size. The view is bound to its view model by `DataTemplate`s like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:IdleViewModel}">
    <v:IdleView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now I would like to make this application available for a second LCD display type. The view will be totally different. Is there any way to bind the view model to a different view depending the resolution?

Comment: Is the screen resolution fixed during application runtime or can it change?

Comment: No, it can not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to do this depending on your requirements. Let me focus on two different approaches that might work for you. How to find out the screen resolution is another topic, see:

- [How to get the size of the current screen in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927540/how-to-get-the-size-of-the-current-screen-in-wpf)

### Data Template Selector

You can create a data template selector that returns a `DataTemplate` based on screen resolution. The mechanism to determine the screen resolution is take from the question above.

```
public class ResolutionDependentTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
   public DataTemplate InvalidResolutionTemplate { get; set; }
   public DataTemplate Resolution1Template { get; set; }
   public DataTemplate Resolution2Template { get; set; }

   public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
   {
      if (IsTargetResolution(480, 576))
         return Resolution1Template;

      if (IsTargetResolution(720, 480))
         return Resolution2Template;

      return InvalidResolutionTemplate;
   }

   private bool IsTargetResolution(double width, double height)
   {
      return Math.Abs(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - width) < 1 &&
             Math.Abs(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - height) < 1;
   }
}
```

You can assign this selector in XAML. Since I do not know which control you are using, this example uses a simple `ContentControl`. The property to assign it to may vary.

```
<ContentControl>
   <ContentControl.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="Resolution1Template">
         <!-- ...your markup. -->
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="Resolution2Template">
         <!-- ...your markup. -->
      </DataTemplate>
   </ContentControl.Resources>
   <ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
      <local:ResolutionDependentTemplateSelector Resolution1Template="{StaticResource Resolution1Template}"
                                                 Resolution2Template="{StaticResource Resolution2Template}"/>
   </ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
</ContentControl>
```

### Resource Dictionaries

You could create separate resource dictionaries that contain the data template for each different screen along with other specific resources that only apply to a certain screen size. Then on startup (e.g. in the `App`s `OnStartup` method), merge the resource dictionary that fits the screen resolution into the application resources (`App.Resources`).

---

Depending on the size and complexity of your application you could separate the controls for each distinct screen resolution into its own project, similar to the resource dictionary approach. If the application is always run on a specific LCD type and never on another, it would also be possible to create targets for each, so each *"platform"* contains only the resources it needs.

Comment: I went with the Resource dictionary approach. Because I have a lot of Views. Based on the screen resolution I select the corresponding DataTemplates.xaml file and add them to the MergedDictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to bind the view model to a different view depending the resolution?

Not using a single view model type and a corresponding `DataTemplate` alone.

You could either

- Use two different view model types and views
- Implement the view to adopt itself according to the view model (which should then know about the current screen resolution)
- Use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/xaml-basics-datatemplateselector/) to select the appropriate view based on some logic other than just the type of the view model